# Must declare the scalar variable using internal tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

For some reason, I get the mentioned error message while using two internal tables, declared at the beginning of the script.
I can insert data into the tables, but when I try to join them on a field, present in both tables it wount let me.
I am working in SQL2012

```
SELECT * 
FROM @ITAB01
JOIN @ITAB02
on @ITAB01.country=@ITAB02.country
```

> Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@ITAB01".. Error 137. SQLSTATE 42000. Severity 15. MsgState 2. Line 83.

Comment: Provide the table declarations please

Comment: Do you have separate batches in the query?  ie. Do you use `GO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a name to the table variable.

NOT LIKE THIS:

```
declare @t1 table
(
    p1 int
)

declare @t2 table
(
    p2 int
)

select *
from @t1,
@t2
where @t1.p1 = @t2.p2
```

BUT LIKE THIS:

```
declare @t1 table
(
    p1 int
)

declare @t2 table
(
    p2 int
)

select *
from @t1 t1,
@t2 t2
where t1.p1 = t2.p2
```

So in your case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @ITAB01 ITAB01
JOIN @ITAB02 ITAB02
on ITAB01.country=ITAB02.country
```

Comment: amazing how the title was misleading and any body could wonder ,tables are not declared +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to the tables elsewhere in the query (outside of the `FROM` clause), introduce aliases:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @ITAB01 t1
JOIN @ITAB02 t2
on t1.country=t2.country
```

Aliases are also useful because you can shorten long names. They're also required once you want to use the same table more than once in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Table variables are visible in only the batch they are created.there are many reasons where they can go out of scope like dynamic sql,Go statemnts..

So check your code and see where there are going out of scope.I also recommend using Temp tables if your tables contain more than 1000 records